# How can I have cyclic or forward ReferenceField when using reverse_delete_rule in MongoEngine?

Tags: forward-declaration, mongoengine, cyclic-reference

This code bombs:

```
from mongoengine import *

class Employee(Document):
    name = StringField()
    boss = ReferenceField("Employee", reverse_delete_rule = NULLIFY)
```

Heres the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[…]/mongoengine/base.py", line 791, in __new__
    new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, attrs)
  File "[…]/mongoengine/base.py", line 630, in __new__
    f.document_type.register_delete_rule(new_class,
    File "[…]/mongoengine/fields.py", line 757, in document_type
    self.document_type_obj = get_document(self.document_type_obj)
  File "[…]/mongoengine/base.py", line 136, in get_document
    """.strip() % name)
mongoengine.base.NotRegistered: `Employee` has not been registered
in the document registry.
Importing the document class automatically registers it, has it
been imported?
```

Removing the `reverse_delete_rule` fixes the problem, but I would like to have this rule.

I tried this, and it works, but it really looks like crap, and I fear that there might be bad side-effects (so far, I have not seen any, though):

```
from mongoengine import *

class Employee(Document):
    pass # required for the reverse_delete_rule to work on the boss field,
         # because the Employee class needs to exist.

class Employee(Document):
    name = StringField()
    boss = ReferenceField("Employee", reverse_delete_rule = NULLIFY)
```

Any ideas?  Shouldn't this be considered a bug in MongoEngine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use `'self'` instead `'Employee'`:

```
from mongoengine import *

class Employee(Document):
    name = StringField()
    boss = ReferenceField("self", reverse_delete_rule = NULLIFY)
```

See details: https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#reference-fields.

Comment: Thanks, it works!  This solves the "self" problem, but not the "forward" problem (if I need to reference a class defined later)?

Comment: Probably better use `GenericReferenceField` (https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#generic-reference-fields) for this case.